# docker COPY with file globbing

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

Inside the dockerfile, I want to specify a copy operation for files which are defined by globbing and I want it to be copied with the path as well. So, something like this:

```
COPY ./src/**/project.json /app/**/
```

Considering I have the following structure:

```
./src/bar/project.json
./src/foo/project.json
```

The destination should look like this:

```
/app/bar/project.json
/app/foo/project.json
```

but apparently, this doesn't work and I really don't want to specify all of the COPY operations separately if I have a chance. Any idea how to do this?

> Note that I cannot basically ignore other files through `.dockerignore` [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35671942/463785) as I am going to copy the other files from the same folder after ruining a package install operation. So, the dockerfile is similar to this:
>
> ```
> FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1
>
> COPY ./src/**/project.json /app/**/
> WORKDIR /app/ModernShopping.Auth
> RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
> ADD ./src /app
>
> EXPOSE 44300
> ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "web"]
> ```

Comment: seems like this is not there yet: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15858

Comment: Got the same sort of issue here hope they add it soon: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15771#issuecomment-225786238

Comment: Why do you not do a three way copy? First copy everything to some temp folder with COPY. Then you do `RUN yourcopycommand only-my-proj-files-from-temp`, next is `RUN dnu restore` and afterwards another `RUN yourcopycommand the-remaining-files-from-temp`. Last is temp folder cleanup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker COPY with folder wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786035/docker-copy-with-folder-wildcards)

Answer (score 8):

For any non-standard build operation, I prefer wrapping the `docker build` command in a script (named '`build`').
Here I would

- create a subfolder `tmp` (just beside the `Dockerfile`, in order to keep it in the `docker build` context)
- make the shell `cp` with globing: `cp ./src/**/project.json tmp`
- call `docker build`, with a `Dockerfile` including `COPY tmp/ /app/`
- deleting `tmp`.

That way, I pre-configure what I need from host, before building the image from the host context.

Comment: For anyone still reading this, if you are building out a NodeJS app, gulp works great for this.

Answer (score 7):

Workaround

`Dockerfile`:

```
COPY src/ /app/
```

`.dockerignore`:

```
**
!**/project.json
```

Comment: The downside is that I will be copyig everything else after another operation (`dnu restore`). So, `.dockerignore` will be a problem there.

Comment: Cool workaround for what I asked. I should have made the question more clear, updated it now.

Comment: For me it was a great workaround to using the nonexistent ** wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

Little late, but with multistage building, you can get this behavior. Here I do it for a large maven build

```
FROM maven:3.6-slim as staging

WORKDIR /src/
COPY . .
RUN mkdir /poms/ \
    && find ./ -type d -exec mkdir -p '/poms/{}' \; \
    && find ./ -name pom.xml -exec cp -r '{}' '/poms/{}' \;

FROM maven:3.6-slim as builder

WORKDIR /src/

COPY --from=staging /poms/* ./
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
```

A bit of a hack, but given that it's a multistage, the first stage just get's thrown away and the copy is a cheap operation

Comment: I was using a similar solution to this. The problem with it is it would repeat the dependency goal for every code change (it would not be cached)