# How to nuke everything inside my Docker containers and start a new?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

(I'm clearly haven't fully mastered Docker's concepts yet, so please do correct me when I'm incorrectly/inaccurately using terms.)

I was running out of storage space, so I ran `docker system prune` to clean up my system a bit. However, shortly (perhaps immediately) after that, I started running into segmentation faults after starting Webpack dev server in my container. My guess at this point would be that that is due to some npm package having to be rebuilt, but it not doing so due to some old artefacts still lingering around? I'm not running into the segmentation faults if I run Webpack dev server outside of the container:

```
web_1       | [2] Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1       | [2] webpack output is served from /
web_1       | [2] 404s will fallback to /index.html
web_1       | [2] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
web_1       | [2] error Command failed with exit code 139.
```

Thus, I'm wondering whether `docker system prune` really removes everything related to the Docker images I've run before, or whether there's some additional cleanup I can do.

My Dockerfile is a follows, where `./stacks/frontend` is the directory from which Webpack dev server is run (through `yarn start`):

```
FROM node:6-alpine
LABEL Name="Flockademic dev environment" \
      Version="0.0.0"
ENV NODE_ENV=development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Needed for one of the npm dependencies (fibers, when compiling node-gyp):
RUN apk add --no-cache python make g++
COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
# Unfortunately it seems like Docker can't properly glob this at this time:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670907/docker-copy-with-file-globbing
COPY ["stacks/frontend/package.json", "stacks/frontend/yarn.lock", "stacks/frontend/package-lock*.json", "./stacks/frontend/"]
COPY ["stacks/accounts/package.json", "stacks/accounts/yarn.lock", "stacks/accounts/package-lock*.json", "./stacks/accounts/"]
COPY ["stacks/periodicals/package.json", "stacks/periodicals/yarn.lock", "stacks/periodicals/package-lock*.json", "./stacks/periodicals/"]
RUN yarn install # Also runs `yarn install` in the subdirectories
EXPOSE 3000 8000
CMD yarn start
```

And this is its section in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: flockademic
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app/:rw
    # Prevent locally installed node_modules from being mounted inside the container.
    # Unfortunately, this does not appear to be possible for every stack without manually enumerating them:
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    - /usr/src/app/stacks/frontend/node_modules
    - /usr/src/app/stacks/accounts/node_modules
    - /usr/src/app/stacks/periodicals/node_modules
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      # Some environment variables I use
```

I'm getting somewhat frustrated with not having a clear picture of what's going on :) Any suggestions on how to completely restart (and what concepts I'm getting wrong) would be appreciated.

Comment: you can check if `docker images` shows really nothing

Comment: Hmm, that does indeed still list a number of images. Time to find out how to remove those, I guess... **Edit:** `docker image prune --all`, I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So apparently `docker system prune` has [some additional options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#options), and the proper way to nuke everything was `docker system prune --all --volumes`. The key for me was probably `--volumes`, as those would probably hold cached packages that had to be rebuilt.

The segmentation fault is gone now \o/

Comment: IIRC I can only do that two days after the question was posted :)