# Docker COPY files using glob pattern?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I have a monorepo managed by Yarn, I'd like to take advantage of the Docker cache layers to speed up my builds, to do so I'd like to first copy the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files, run `yarn install` and then copy the rest of the files.

This is my repo structure:

```
packages/one/package.json
packages/one/index.js
packages/two/package.json
packages/two/index.js
package.json
yarn.lock
```

And this is the interested part of the Dockerfile:

```
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY packages/**/package.json ./
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile
COPY . .
```

The problem is that the 3rd `COPY` command doesn't copy anything, how can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: Related: [docker COPY with file globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670907/docker-copy-with-file-globbing)

Comment: Basically what you'd like to do can't work as is, because the specified target folder is the same for several files *that have the same name* (package.json). Similarly, the Bash command `cp packages/*/package.json ./` wouldn't yield something sensible. So I believe you should hard-code in your `Dockerfile` the path of folders `one` and `two`...

Comment: so, which solution did you choose?

Comment: I haven't chosen any of them. I can't use external scripts in my environment.

Comment: Possible solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786035/docker-copy-with-folder-wildcards

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is a solution based on [multistage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) feature:

```sh
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", "./"]
# Step 2: Copy whole app
COPY packages packages

# Step 3: Find and remove non-package.json files
RUN find packages \! -name "package.json" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -print | xargs rm -rf

# Step 4: Define second build stage
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /app
# Step 5: Copy files from the first build stage.
COPY --from=0 /app .

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .

# To restore workspaces symlinks
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

CMD yarn start
```

On `Step 5` the layer cache will be reused even if any file in `packages` directory has changed.

Comment: Your 4th layer: 
`COPY packages packages` break the cache. So `COPY --from=0 /app .` will be recalculated over and over again for every build.

Comment: I made a simple experiment and compared layer hashes then:

1. `docker build …`.
2. `docker image inspect IMAGE_NAME`.
3. Modify a source file.
4. Repeat step 1 and 2.

I had 9 layers for each image and only two layers are different. @LivneRosenblum Would you explain why you think it breaks the cache? As I see the most expensive layer with `yarn install` is reusing between runs.

Comment: Reuse is probably due to the newer versions (or buildkit). I too would expect that layer to be reused as long as input for the hash calculation (package.json's) do not change (and the rest of the files are removed in a previous step that is obviously not cached).

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned in the [official Dockerfile reference for `COPY <src> <dest>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from `<src>` and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path `<dest>`.

For your case

> Each  may contain wildcards and matching will be done using Go’s `filepath.Match` rules.

These are [the rules](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match). They contain this:

> '*'         matches any sequence of non-Separator characters

So try to use `*` instead of `**` in your pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that as well but it does the same (nothing)

Comment: I just tried it with this dockerfile, and it works:

```FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
COPY */*.csproj /app/
```
When I ran it, here is the correct output:

```$ docker run --rm -ti temp ls /app
foo.csproj  bar.csproj
```

Comment: Any idea how to make the folder structure match when it gets copied? Using just this makes it all go to the current directory

Comment: @GiovanniBassi, the script in your comment doesn’t work as expected. Each .csproj should be copied to appropriate subfolder(e.g. app/foo/foo.csproj) not to the root app/foo.csproj

Answer (score 19):

If you can't technically enumerate all the subdirectories at stake in the Dockerfile (namely, writing `COPY packages/one/package.json packages/one/` for each one), but want to copy all the files in two steps and take advantage of Docker's caching feature, you can try the following workaround:

- Devise a wrapper script (say, in bash) that copies the required `package.json` files to a separate directory (say, `.deps/`) built with a similar hierarchy, then call `docker build …`
- Adapt the Dockerfile to copy (and rename) the separate directory beforehand, and then call `yarn install --pure-lockfile`…

All things put together, this could lead to the following files:

**./build.bash**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tag="image-name:latest"

rm -f -r .deps  # optional, to be sure that there is
# no extraneous "package.json" from a previous build

find . -type d \( -path \*/.deps \) -prune -o \
  -type f \( -name "package.json" \) \
  -exec bash -c 'dest=".deps/$1" && \
    mkdir -p -- "$(dirname "$dest")" && \
    cp -av -- "$1" "$dest"' bash '{}' \;
# instead of mkdir + cp, you may also want to use
# rsync if it is available in your environment...

sudo docker build -t "$tag" .
```

and

**./Dockerfile**:

```dockerfile
FROM …

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# COPY package.json .  # subsumed by the following command
COPY .deps .
# and not "COPY .deps .deps", to avoid doing an extra "mv"
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

COPY . .
# Notice that "COPY . ." will also copy the ".deps" folder; this is
# maybe a minor issue, but it could be avoided by passing more explicit
# paths than just "." (or by adapting the Dockerfile and the script and
# putting them in the parent folder of the Yarn application itself...)
```

Answer (score 19):

Using Docker's new BuildKit executor it has become possible to use a bind mount into the Docker context, from which you can then copy any files as needed.

For example, the following snippet copies all package.json files from the Docker context into the image's `/app/` directory (the workdir in the below example)

Unfortunately, changing any file in the mount still results in a layer cache miss. This can be worked around using the multi-stage approach [as presented by @mbelsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63142468/171436), but this time the explicit deletion is no longer needed.

```bash
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM ... AS packages

WORKDIR /app/
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/docker-context \
    cd /docker-context/; \
    find . -name "package.json" -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 4 -exec cp --parents "{}" /app/ \;

FROM ...

WORKDIR /app/
COPY --from=packages /app/ .
```

The `mindepth`/`maxdepth` arguments are specified to reduce the number of directories to search, this can be adjusted/removed as desirable for your use-case.

It may be necessary to enable the BuildKit executor using environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`, as the traditional executor silently ignores the bind mounts.

More information about BuildKit and bind bounds [can be found here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/7641cbf96184bd14b127d2565869e62c1827a1c9/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#build-mounts-run---mount).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it and it's worth mentioning that changing any file (not only `package.json`) will cause the copy step to run again so in that sense, it has no advantage over just copying the whole code and run `npm install`

Comment: @Arik oh, that is interesting! And a bit surprising to me; I would expect that the resulting image would have the same SHA, hence allowing subsequent layers to be reused. I have seen this work but you may be correct that it was only when nothing else changed. Needs more investigation to see if this can be made to work then!

Comment: @Arik Some experiments led me to believe that the multi-stage trick is still necessary to achieve the desired layer caching. I have updated to example accordingly. Thanks for your observation and comment!

Comment: I've added my solution as an answer

Comment: This is absolutely amazing!!! @Joost, this completely solved my problem and I will apply this to A LOT of images! thank you!

Comment: I've tried it, but it just doesn't work as expected. I.e. the 'COPY --from=packages /app/ .' step will not be cached, when there are _any_ changes in the /docker-context dir
I think the issue is that cp --parents doesn't preserve the file/directory permissions

Answer (score 2):

Following @Joost suggestion, I've created a `dockerfile` that utilizes the power of BuildKit to achieve the following:

- Faster `npm install` by moving npm's cache directory to the build cache
- Skipping `npm install` if nothing changed in `package.json` files since last successful build

Pseudo Code:

- Get all `package.json` files from the build context
- Compare them to the `package.json` files from the last successful build
- If changes were found, run `npm install` and cache the `package.json` files + `node_modules` folder
- Copy the `node_modules` (fresh or cached) to the desired location in the image

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder

# https://github.com/opencollective/opencollective/issues/1443
RUN apk add --no-cache ncurses

# must run as root
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

WORKDIR /app

# get a temporary copy of the package.json files from the build context
RUN --mount=id=website-packages,type=bind,target=/tmp/builder \
    cd /tmp/builder/ && \
    mkdir /tmp/packages && \
    chown 1000:1000 /tmp/packages && \
    find ./ -name "package.json" -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 6 -exec cp --parents "{}" /tmp/packages/ \;

# check if package.json files were changed since the last successful build
RUN --mount=id=website-build-cache,type=cache,target=/tmp/builder,uid=1000 \
    mkdir -p /tmp/builder/packages && \
    cd /tmp/builder/packages && \
    (diff -qr ./ /tmp/packages/ || (touch /tmp/builder/.rebuild && echo "Found an updated package.json"));

USER node

COPY --chown=node:node . /app

# run `npm install` if package.json files were changed, or use the cached node_modules/
RUN --mount=id=website-build-cache,type=cache,target=/tmp/builder,uid=1000 \
    echo "Creating NPM cache folders" && \
    mkdir -p /tmp/builder/.npm && \
    mkdir -p /tmp/builder/modules && \
    echo "Copying latest package.json files to NPM cache folders" && \
    /bin/cp -rf /tmp/packages/* /tmp/builder/modules && \
    cd /tmp/builder/modules && \
    echo "Using NPM cache folders" && \
    npm config set cache /tmp/builder/.npm && \
    if test -f /tmp/builder/.rebuild; then (echo "Installing NPM packages" && npm install --no-fund --no-audit --no-optional --loglevel verbose); fi && \
    echo "copy cached NPM packages" && \
    /bin/cp -rfT /tmp/builder/modules/node_modules /app/node_modules && \
    rm -rf /tmp/builder/packages && \
    mkdir -p /tmp/builder/packages && \
    cd /app && \
    echo "Caching package.json files" && \
    find ./ -name "package.json" -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 6 -exec cp --parents "{}" /tmp/builder/packages/ \; && \
    (rm /tmp/builder/.rebuild 2> /dev/null || true);
```

Note:
I'm only using the `node_modules` of the root folder, as in my case, all the packages from inner folders are hoisted to the root

Answer (score -9):

just use `.dockerignore` to filter out not needed files. [refer this reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

in your cases, add this to your .dockerignore.

`*.js
    any file to skip copy`

I assume your files are located like `/home/package.json`, and want to copy those files to `/dest` in docker.

Dockerfile would look like this.

`COPY /home /dest`

this will copy all files to /home directory except list in `.dockerignore`

Comment: How am I supposed to copy the rest of the files then?

Comment: @FezVrasta It will recursively copy entire directory except listed in `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: Exactly. Please read the question. I need to copy that whole directory, but in two steps