# Specify multiple files in ARG to COPY in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, copy, dockerfile

Consider the following docker build context:

```
src/
  hi
  there
  bye
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN mkdir test
COPY src/hi src/there test/
```

This works just fine but I would like to make the list of files to copy an `ARG`, something like:

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG files

RUN mkdir test
COPY ${files} test/
```

Unfortunately calling with `docker build --build-arg files='src/hi src/there' some_path` fails because it treats `src/hi src/there` as a single item. How can I "expand" the `files` argument into multiple files to copy?

On a whim I tried specifying the files arg multiple times: `docker build --build-arg files='src/hi' --build-arg files='src/there' some_path`, but this only copies "there".

Comment: You should consider about excluding files into another directory (e.g project_root/docker/....) and copy entire directory. It would be much cleaner.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but unfortunately that wouldn't work for me since it's a matter of copying some files first then doing some stuff then copying some other files later. The point being to make better use of the cache. The set of files will change depending on the build type

Comment: I have the exact same problem!

Comment: Did you try with double quotes? like: _docker build --build-arg files="src/hi src/there" some_path_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this again years later but now found an adequate solution, assuming the files can be grouped into a fixed set of categories.

The answer is basically combining the answers of [Docker COPY files using glob pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939960/docker-copy-files-using-glob-pattern) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59112/preserve-directory-structure-when-moving-files-using-find

Conceptually, the idea is to separate the groups of files in one stage, then copy each group one by one (or ignoring it).

In code:

```
# Create dummy stage for splitting up files
FROM ubuntu as src
RUN mkdir /groups
WORKDIR /groups
RUN mkdir group1 group2
# Makes `group2` the de-facto default, can be any though
COPY src group2
RUN rsync --recursive --remove-source-files --prune-empty-dirs \
    --include='hi' \
    --include='there' \
    --exclude='*' \
    group2/ group1/

# Create the image we actually care about
FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=src /groups/group1 test/
RUN commands requiring only `group1` files
COPY --from=src /groups/group2 test/
RUN commands requiring all files
```

Answer (score 2):

> because it treats `src/hi src/there` as a single item.
> How can I "expand" the files argument into multiple files to copy?

That seems unlikely considering the [Dockerfile format](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format) mentions, regarding arguments:

> whitespace in instruction arguments, such as the commands following `RUN`, are preserved

And that is not limited to `RUN`.

[`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), however, also includes:

> Each `<src>` may contain wildcards and matching will be done using Go’s [`filepath.Match`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath#Match) rules.

It would not work in your case.

Remain the [multi-stage builds approach](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

- COPY `src` (the all folder)
- Remove everything you don't want:

  ```
  RUN find pip ${files} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print | xargs rm -rf
  ```
- Build your actual image based on the resulting state of the first image.

You can pass as one argument the folders you want to preserve

```
docker build --build-arg="files=! -path "src/hi" ! -path "src/there"" .
```

See an example in "[Docker `COPY` files using glob pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63142468/6309)".

Comment: You propose the following two explainations for the problem of variable expansion as distinct command argument:
- Spaces are preserved in command arguments: This means spaces in command arguments are not modified, but isn't related to whether spaces withing a variable are interpreted. As a single argument containing spaces or as multiple elements separated by spaces.
- Pattern matching follows Go's rule: There is no pattern matching at play here. Those are fully specified files and dirs.
Those seems to address related but distinct subject.

Comment: @AntoineGallix Still, the point remains: a multi-stage approach with a full copy and a subsequent filter will work.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible workaround, you can try to use `.dockerignore` file

```
*
!src/hi
!src/there
```

with

```
COPY . test/
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

> Finally, you may want to specify which files to include in the
> context, rather than which to exclude. To achieve this, specify * as
> the first pattern, followed by one or more ! exception patterns.

Update:

Using wildcards in `.dockerignore` is limited because of bug:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30018

Answer (score 0):

From the Docker documentation, for your information.

If you have multiple Dockerfile steps that use different files from your context, COPY them individually, rather than all at once. This ensures that each step’s build cache is only invalidated (forcing the step to be re-run) if the specifically required files change.